# Trying to find how to link three tables together

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-key-relationship

At the moment I have three tables that I am trying to connect and figure out what queries will get the results I need and also follow best practices. MySQL is still pretty new to me, and this is my first stumbling block that I can't figure out.

I am trying to build a simple URL shortener that can "link" multiple long URLs to one short URL. I basically want to have a link www.example.com/google then have google.com, google.co.uk, google.it, etc... and GEO target when the user accesses the link.

My three tables are set up as:

short_id | user_id | short_url                 //Short URL Table

long_id | user_id | long_url  | country_code   //Long URL table

user_id | name | password | email | created    //User table

I am not sure if foreign keys are the best route. Also, I understand how to add a user, but what queries would I have to run to have a user add a short/long url and have the user_id field in "user" table match the user_id fields in the other tables.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from short_url_table
left join long_url_table
using (user_id) 
left join user_table 
using (user_id) ;
```